# Expressions starting with 'as' - does 'as' imply a rhetorical obviousness?

Tags: parts-of-speech, rhetorical-devices

Being a non-native speaker I might have the wrong instinct about this, but I feel a common theme in the following expressions:

- as God is my witness
- as I hope to be saved
- as you value your life

To me, they seem to convey that whatever else is said before/after is underpinned by the axiomatic nature of the phrase. That is, they imply:

- I wouldn't lie because *obviously* God is always a witness to my actions
- I wouldn't lie because *obviously* I want to be saved
- you should do [whatever] because *obviously* you don't want to lose your life

Is there something to this, or am I off beam? Also, which part of speech and meaning of 'as' is used here?

Comment: *as* does not imply *obviously* in these cases, only *because* (or, more directly, *since*).

Comment: I can't find supporting evidence, but I'm fairly sure that this is the 'to the extent that / with the degree of seriousness you would (and probably soon will) consider the fact that' _as_, and not the 'since / because' _as_. So these would be equivalent to say 'treating this as being a life-and-death matter ...'. As important as life itself.

Comment: In another [thread](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/52486/113371) 'as' was defined differently (for 'as God is my witness') - denoting concurrence instead of causality. I found that a bit awkward, but 'since' also sounds strange in context.

Comment: From the internet: "Take care, as you value your life, ..." Obviously the 'as much as' meaning. It's hard to suggest an original, but something along the lines of "Take as much care as you consider the value your life warrants ..."

Comment: @EdwinAshworth From the bare bones of what the OP has given us, I don't see how we can say for sure which *as* it is. At least that is the case for 2 and 3. But I think you are right so far as 1 is concerned.

Comment: @WS2 I'm assuming that OP's 'I feel a common theme in the following expressions:' means that they haven't got silly contrivances like 'I thought that, as you value your life, you would like to spend the extra $100 on a better crash-helmet' in mind.

Comment: I think [as God is my witness](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=as+God+is+my+witness&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cas%20God%20is%20my%20witness%3B%2Cc0) only survives as a "fixed phrase". On the other hand, I'm pretty sure I've *never* heard anyone say ***as** you value your [life, sanity, whatever]* - it's an archaic construction where everyone today would use ***if***, not ***as***..

Comment: @WS2 I don't really understand why you consider the question 'bare bones'? These are existing phrases I have encountered in several (mostly) 19th century novels, not ad hoc, one-off sentences undecipherable out of context. I am more or less aware of their meaning; it's the grammatical structure (and the role of 'as' in it) that's confusing for me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Indeed, these are possibly archaic constructions. Still, 'as' must have had some kind of grammatical function in them.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Your explanations do make sense to me (thank you!) but I couldn't find any corresponding definition of 'as' (i.e. 'as much as' or 'to the extent that') in Oxford, MW, Wiktionary etc.

Comment: @Bepe: ***As*** I said, it used to perform much the same "grammatical function" as the word ***if***, as invariably used in similar constructions today. On the strictly *semantic* level though, obviously Edwin's *to the extent that* is the essential "meaning".

Comment: OED **as** definition 8b ***To the same extent as**, in so far as; in proportion as; according as; just as, even as. **Now rare except in certain set expressions**.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Sorry, I was a bit careless when answering you. As = if sounds good, though I don't understand how major online dictionaries usually listing archaic meanings alongside current ones all fail to mention this.

Comment: @Bepe: I think it's stretching a point to say "as" *means* "if" in such constructions - it just performs much the same *function* (but in many contexts, so does "since").

Comment: I've not tended to interpret "as ..." in this sort of context as implying "obviousness" so much as a degree of sincerity or finality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 1720, *as God is my witness* appears to be an oath of honesty, invoking the omniscience of God to corroborate a man's own testimony. From [*The Dying Speeches and Behaviour of the Several State Prisoners That Have Been Executed the Last 300 Years*](https://books.google.com/books?id=bsctAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA388&dq=%22as%20god%20is%20my%20witness%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=N7oAVc-WBsORyATU1YCADg&ved=0CDkQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22as%20god%20is%20my%20witness%22&f=false):

> I take God to witness, I never had one Six-pence, or any thing else,
> to carry on any Design ; and if it were to save my Life now, I cannot
> charge any Man in the World with any Design against the Government, *as
> God* is my Witness, or against his Majesty, or against any other
> Person.

Stephen College had been condemned to die for treason and was reaffirming his innocence at his execution hearing. He invoked God as a witness, and reaffirmed it with the phrase, *as God is my witness*. From the [Corpus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*%20God%20is%20my%20witness&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2C%2A%20God%20is%20my%20witness%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3B_START_%20God%20is%20my%20witness%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bas%20God%20is%20my%20witness%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Band%20God%20is%20my%20witness%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BFor%20God%20is%20my%20witness%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAs%20God%20is%20my%20witness%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfor%20God%20is%20my%20witness%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbut%20God%20is%20my%20witness%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BBut%20God%20is%20my%20witness%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAnd%20God%20is%20my%20witness%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Byet%20God%20is%20my%20witness%3B%2Cc0), this seems to be the predominant use of the phrase, and as such it could be considered a set phrase meaning: *since God testifies with me [I'm telling the truth]*.

In 1839, John Donne and Henry Alford identified the ancient religious origin of this oath in [*The Works*, Volume 1, page 107](https://books.google.com/books?id=pYpUAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA107&dq=%22as%20god%20is%20my%20witness%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=cMQAVdnTNc72yQSfioLYBw&ved=0CEIQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22as%20god%20is%20my%20witness%22&f=false):

> How often does St. Paul, (especially in his epistles to Timothy, and
> to Titus) repeat that phrase, *This is a true and faithful saying*? And
> how often, his juratory caution, before the Lord ; *as God is my
> witness*?

From [Romans 1:9](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans%201%3A9&version=KJV) and [1 Thessalonians 2:5](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Thessalonians%202%3A5&version=KJV) in the King James version of *The Bible*:

> For *God is my witness*, whom I serve with my spirit in the gospel of
> his Son, that without ceasing I make mention of you always in my
> prayers;
>
> For neither at any time used we flattering words, as ye know, nor a
> cloke of covetousness; *God is witness*:

The example of Saint Paul invoking God to establish his honesty became a pattern in the Church of England, throughout the colonies, and as a foundation in the United States. In 1840, W. Jos Walter combined the essence of first two phrases of the OP with the same reinforcement of honesty. During Sir Thomas More's defense at an indictment hearing in [*Sir Thomas More His Life and Times*, page 324:](https://books.google.com/books?id=nx86AAAAcAAJ&pg=PA324&dq=%22as%20god%20is%20my%20witness%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=acoAVZC6Cs-wyATevoG4CQ&ved=0CCEQ6AEwATgK#v=onepage&q=%22as%20god%20is%20my%20witness%22&f=false)

> *As God is my witness*, and *as I look to Him for the salvation of my
> soul*, this was my only answer. All this I trust is no breach of your
> law.

God's testimony corroborates, and my salvation is held as security on the honesty of my statement! In 1899, Sidney Levett-Yeats used *as God is my witness* in an ambiguous way that foreshadowed a major turn in the phrase. From [*The Heart of Denise and Other Tales*:](https://books.google.com/books?id=SuDK915H2LYC&pg=PT87&dq=%22as%20god%20is%20my%20witness%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=48wAVcLHO8j9yQTswoKQDQ&ved=0CDMQ6AEwBDgo#v=onepage&q=%22as%20god%20is%20my%20witness%22&f=false)

> You can say what you please, madame, but we did our best; but *as God
> is my witness* the Huguenots mean death, and I advise you to go. In a
> half-hour it will be too late.

Sidney Levett-Yeats probably meant for us to infer *I'm telling the truth* in this context, but the future focus welcomes a hint of *I'm serious!* which appeared again in 1966, *Bird at My Window*, Page 19:

> I swear to you, if you sign him out and he cause any trouble — *as God
> is my witness*, I ain't going to never have nothing to do with you, nor
> lay sight on you as long as I live.

The phrase seems to be expanding into the truth of a promise: I'm committed! From [*The South and Faulkner's Yoknapatawpha*](https://books.google.com/books?id=LxDYAiHXqd0C&pg=PA178&dq=%22as%20god%20is%20my%20witness%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=9c8AVdPdFsGryASczIHIDw&ved=0CBwQ6AEwADgU#v=onepage&q=%22as%20god%20is%20my%20witness%22&f=false), page 178:

> ...it is precisely the sight of the gutted and ruined Twelve Oaks that
> directly triggers the vow she makes that "'*As God is my witness*, *as
> God is my witness*, the Yankees aren't going to lick me. I'm going to
> live through this and when it's over, I'm never going to be hungry
> again. No, nor any of my folks. If I have to steal or kill — *as God is
> my witness*, I'm never going to be hungry again.

The truthful promise application, has been sealed with the truthful testimony.

In a secular society, where honesty, invoking God as a witness, and offering salvation as security, have become passé, all sorts of things are substituted:

> wanting to describe a 5-pound bass in such a way as to persuade their
> hearers that it was indeed, verily, in absolute truth, as God is my
> witness, by the grass on my mother's grave, in all honesty a 5-pound
> bass, they are obliged, without any alternative, to call it an 8-pound
> bass, since every listener will deduct at least 3 pounds and probably
> more.
>
> [Field & Stream](https://books.google.com/books?id=CHNeTZkDgQoC&pg=PA146&dq=%22as%20god%20is%20my%20witness%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=StIAVcfoD5D8yQSVn4D4Dw&ved=0CFEQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=%22as%20god%20is%20my%20witness%22&f=false) Jun 1981, page 146.

What is more valuable to an "unbeliever" than their own life? But in the second person, it is mostly a threat:

> Well, then, you will call here to-morrow morning about eleven o'clock,
> not before, and (I hardly need repeat it), but I again say— secrecy—*as
> you value your life*.

We can apply a number of technical interpretations of *as*:

- Interjection: *Secrecy, or your life!*
- Comparison: *You should value the secrecy like you value your life.*
- Concurrence: *As long as you value your life, you should value the
  secrecy.*
- Cause: *Since you value your life, you will value secrecy too.*

  The meaning is the same: If you value your life, keep the secret.

**Conclusion**:

As an invocation of supernatural credibility their may be an **undertone** of "obviously" to someone who is convinced of the supernatural, but the issue is not the *obviousness* of the matter, but rather the *honesty* of the matter. On its face the *cause* use of *as* seems to be the strongest, but all of the other uses of *as* find merit too. In the end, the semantic unit *as* seems to be dissolved into the set phrases meaning: **Honestly**! **Seriously**!

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. So, if I look at a list of accepted meanings for 'as', and want to assign one of those meanings to the three phrases, I couldn't properly do it, because the role of 'as' in these phrases is quite intangible?

Comment: *Intangible* is not the word I would use; perhaps *ambiguous* or *interconnected*, and they all seem to point to the comparison center of *as*.

Answer (score 0):

'As God is my witness' means 'To the extent that God is my witness' or '**Insofar as** God is my witness."